# Numbers separated by commas in UITextField not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to add a decimal after every 3 characters. (Counting backwards like this: 1,325,541 instead of 1325451.)

Here is what I tried:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormat setGroupingSeparator:@","];
    [numberFormat setGroupingSize:3];
    [numberFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber *amount = [numberFormat numberFromString:textField.text];
    textField.text = [numberFormat stringFromNumber:amount];
    return YES;
}
```

It doesn't insert a comma after every 3 characters. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You're accessing textField.text in a `should*` method, i.e., before it has been updated by the user's recent change.

Comment: @bgfriend0 this is correct, you should write it in as an answer with the solution.

Comment: Sorry, wrote that quickly and had to run. ;) Looks like Luois has it taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this ends up being a little more nuanced than you might expect, but this is what I came up with:

As @bgfriend0's comment mentions, `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` gets called before applying an edit to a text field (this is useful for other reasons). Meaning, that if your current string was `123` and a user goes to type in `4`, the method would be passed the following as parameters:

- `textField:` the textField, **but note at this point** `textField.text` is `123`
- `range:` NSRange{2, 0}
- `string:` 4

And there is a way to make this function work from within that method, but there's a better way (I think).

After you instantiate your textField, add a target to listen for editing events:

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(formatNumberIfNeeded:)    
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This will get called anytime an editing change happens in a `UITextField`. The `SEL` that we'll be performing will look like this:

```
- (void)formatNumberIfNeeded:(UITextField *)textField{
    // you'll need to strip the commas for the formatter to work properly
    NSString * currentTextWithoutCommas = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

    NSNumber * numberFromString = [numberFormatter numberFromString:currentTextWithoutCommas];
    NSString * formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberFromString];

    textField.text = formattedNumberString;
}
```

Now, things get slightly more tricky if you need to localize, but cross that bridge if needed.

As for `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString`, that's a much better place to do character validation. So, a basic validation to check for letters could look like:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSRange illegalCharacterEntered = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
    if ( illegalCharacterEntered.location != NSNotFound ) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

So with those two bits of code, you'll be able to update the textfield string to include a comma every 3rd character, and users wont be able to enter any letters of the alphabet (but they can still input other 'illegal' characters, so extend that validation as needed).

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer! Is there a way of adding commas instead of decimals?

Comment: `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` does add commas in this manner: `1,234,567,890.00`

Comment: Oops. My bad. Just tried it, and it works!! It's weird they call it decimalStyle even though its commas!

Comment: Now anytime I input a letter, all the numbers in the textField disapears