# Detect whether a character was inserted in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField`. I want to detect if a certain character was imputed. Here is what I tried"

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [textField.text length]; i++) {
        if ([textField.text characterAtIndex:i] == @".") { // Error Here
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error

```
Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'NSStirng ')
```

So what I did is obviously wrong. My question is how can I fix that?

Comment: Use NSString's rangeOfString, and remember that the text field's text when this method is called is not yet changed with the new input.  You can apply stringByReplacingCharactersInRange with the text to form the string that it will contain after you return YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing it to a string when it should be returning a variable type "char". You should use single quotations instead of double. Try this:

```
if([textField.text characterAtIndex:i]=='.')
    //DoSomething
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using : `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString`

**UPDATE**

```
NSString *string1 = @"The quick brown fox jumped";
NSRange match;
match = [string1 rangeOfString: @"brown fox"];

if (match.location == NSNotFound)
          NSLog (@"Match not found");
else
          NSLog (@"match found");
```

Comment: How should I compare it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if ([textField.text characterAtIndex:i] == [@".".characterAtIndex:0])
```

Comment: Why? Just compete against a proper character literal.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to want to have that loop inside of that `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method because that method gets called every time a change is made to a `textField` (adding a character, deleting a character, etc). Meaning, your loop will run `textField.text.length` number of times *any time* there is a change made to `textField.text`.

#### Too many loops:

[image]

---

As explained in  [Numbers separated by commas in UITextField not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711274/numbers-separated-by-commas-in-uitextfield-not-working/29712218#29712218), this method is being called to determine *if* a change should be made. Moreover, because you're checking `textField.text` for the `.` and not `string`, your condition won't be `TRUE` until something is typed in *after* the `.` is added.

#### Called too Late/Often:

[image]

What is the above doing? I took your loop along with the accepted answer and added an `NSLog` to run when we encounter a `.`.
I begin by typing `123` and take a slight pause after typing `.`. You can see, that despite typing `.` the `NSLog` doesn't actually happen until I type the next number. Also, the `NSLog` statement will now run on every new character -- incrementing the number of log messages for each subsequent `.`

---

What's the alternative? Well, thats up to what you need your code to do when the `.` is encountered. But to ensure that you're executing your code at the right time, I would either

1. Check `string` (not `textField.text`) in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` .. and for this check it's a lot simpler:
   `if( [string isEqualToString:@"."] ){ // Do something }`

[image]

or

2. Use the link I posted as a guide and make the textfield a target for editing notifications.

---

Lastly, why does this question merit such a lengthy answer with visual aids? Your question, along with the responses that followed, is a good example of how it's possible to introduce a subtle bug in your code and still get the desired results. `NSLog` is going to be one of your most trusted allies; use it liberally to deconstruct a bug and reverse engineer a solution to your coding problems/questions.