# Delete a letter in UITextField not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711274/numbers-separated-by-commas-in-uitextfield-not-working/29712218#29712218) to make the numbers format with commas. The problem is, that whenever a **letter** gets inputted, everything in the `textView` gets removed.

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(formatNumberIfNeeded:)    
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)formatNumberIfNeeded:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSString * currentTextWithoutCommas = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

    NSNumber * numberFromString = [numberFormatter numberFromString:currentTextWithoutCommas];
    NSString * formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberFromString];

    textField.text = formattedNumberString;
}
```

I tried inserting the following code in `shouldChangeTextInRange`:

```
NSCharacterSet *numbersOnly = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
for (int i = 0; i < [textField.text length]; i++)
{
    unichar c = [textField.text characterAtIndex:i];
    if (![numbersOnly characterIsMember:c]) {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

That didn't do the trick. So I put that in `formatNumberIfNeeded` (before everything else), and instead of `return NO;` I inserted:

```
textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:c withString:@""];
```

And that gave me an error. Not sure what I should do next.

Error:

```
ERROR Implicit conversion of 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short') to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
WARNING Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'unichar (aka 'unsigned short') to parameter of type 'NSString *'
```

Comment: Write the error, write the error, write the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried same snippet which you followed and it works fine. Check below snippets and screenshots.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    
    [self.txtField addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(formatNumberIfNeeded:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];    
}

- (void)formatNumberIfNeeded:(UITextField *)textField{
    // you'll need to strip the commas for the formatter to work properly
    NSString * currentTextWithoutCommas = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

    NSNumber * numberFromString = [numberFormatter numberFromString:currentTextWithoutCommas];
    NSString * formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberFromString];

    textField.text = formattedNumberString;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSRange illegalCharacterEntered = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
    if ( illegalCharacterEntered.location != NSNotFound ) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try entering a letter? (a,b,c...)

Comment: when you are using numberFormatter then why are you entering letters? First you have to clear with your requirement.

Comment: I'm just doing checks. They can using external keyboards

Comment: with numberFormatter even if you try entering letters it will not allow. I have checked its not inserting letters to the textfield. i am neither getting any errors nor crash

Comment: What happens when you enter a letter?

Comment: Its not inserting any letter. I checked inserting at the beginning & after numbers also. Cursor just keep focusing but not allow any letters to insert. Its not deleting any numbers when i tried inserting after numbers.

Comment: The delegate wasn't set self. That was my problem. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `keyboardType` property for the `UITextView` which prevent from entering a letter.

```
 [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

choose a suitabe keyboard type from the enum list

```
typedef enum {
UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,             // A number pad including a decimal point
UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,                // Optimized for entering Twitter messages (shows # and @)
UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch,              // Optimized for URL and search term entry (shows space and .)

UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

Comment: It's not good if that's the only prevention. First: they could be using an external keyboard. Second: I'm pretty sure you can change the keyboard type when the app is running.